# Search for values where 2 columns matches and get the smallest one

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

For example having this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | NUMBER1
Fruit | Pear | 2
Fruit | Pear | 3
Fruit | Pear | 4
Fruit | Kiwi | 7
Fruit | Kiwi | 9
Car   | Honda| 4
Car   | Honda| 5
```

A fourth column would have the smallest number for each row that matches the first two columns:

```
Col1 | Col2 | NUMBER1 | COMPARED NUMBER
Fruit | Pear | 2      | 2
Fruit | Pear | 3      | 2
Fruit | Pear | 4      | 2
Fruit | Kiwi | 7      | 7
Fruit | Kiwi | 9      | 7
Car   | Honda| 4      | 4
Car   | Honda| 5      | 4
```

Is it possible too make a function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), try this in D2 and fill down,

```
=aggregate(15, 6, (c$2:c$8)/((a$2:a$8=a2)*(b$2:b$8=b2)), 1)
```

In [excel-2016](/questions/tagged/excel-2016) or [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) use this in D2 and fill down.

```
=minifs(C$2:C$8, A$2:A$8, A2, B$2:B$8, B2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell D2:

`=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(vlookup(A2:A&B2:B,QUERY({A2:A&B2:B,C2:C},"order by Col1, Col2"),2,0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your data is sorted by ColC,ColB and then ColA,

D2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,B$2:C$12,2,0)
```

#### Sorted Table:

```
Col1 | Col2 | NUMBER1
Fruit | Pear | 2
Fruit | Pear | 3
Fruit | Pear | 4
Fruit | Kiwi | 7
Fruit | Kiwi | 9
Car   | Honda| 4
Car   | Honda| 5
```

#### Result

```
Col1 | Col2 | NUMBER1 | Compared Number
Fruit | Pear | 2      | 2 [=VLOOKUP(B2,B$2:C$12,2,0)]
Fruit | Pear | 3      | 2
Fruit | Pear | 4      | 2
Fruit | Kiwi | 7      | 7
Fruit | Kiwi | 9      | 7
Car   | Honda| 4      | 4
Car   | Honda| 5      | 4
```